# Is there an NLP framework for extracting text from larger content

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, gensim, nlu

I have some technical documents that I need to extract the text from regarding a specific set of procedures.  Is there an easy off-the-shelf way to 'show' a language model the text to be extracted and each of the documents and then have it extract that text programmatically?

I was thinking of taking each paragraph and taking like a mean of all the word embeddings within the paragraph to create a 'paragraph embedding' and essentially comparing those to the 'paragraph embeddings' of the training set extracted text but I didn't know if there was a more robust way of doing that.

Comment: You may want to look into doc2vec.  You could try applying it at a per-paragraph level and finding the vectors that are closest to your examples.

Comment: Interesting.  One of the problems that I see with that is the addition of any document into the corpus will require retraining of the entire dataset.  I was hoping for something that might be more easily extensible to other technical documents.

Comment: Is your goal more in the realm of finding the answers to specific questions, or using example text as a query-by-example for more similar text? (What happens to the passages selected? Do you have any training set, or ways to create a training set, with examples of 'query' texts and then which parts of other texts you'd most like to see in response?)

Comment: 1) some yes, some not really, it’s e.g. just finding all the methods across all documents. Ingredients across all documents. Percent efficiency across all documents. Etc. The last one for instance is a simple question. But method is returning a whole section. It’s not Q&A-able because it would require more than 512 tokens to ingest the entire document.  2) Some are returned as is, some are broken down further 3) I have 5 documents broken down this way and a sixth I’m keeping as validation. 

Currently I’ve had some success in e.g. the methods, using mean word embeddings per paragraph.